# Eclipse syntax highlighting

Tags: eclipse, cfeclipse

I am trying to add CFeclipse highlighting to *.js files but it is not working in the Luna version of Eclipse I try going to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Content Types and adding it there but the syntax highlighting does not appear.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find the JavaScript syntax highlighting for CFEclipse deficient. I greatly prefer the syntax highlighting provided by JavaScript Development Tools, part of the Eclipse Web Developer Tools package provided by Eclipse Web Tools Platform.